# Error al usar nmap.PortScanner() en python3

Tags: python, nmap

estoy intentando usar el modulo nmap en python. Primero lo instale con

```
pip3 install nmap
```

y cuando hacia nmap.PortScanner() me daba un error

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'
>>>
```

Pero entonces descubri que necesitaba instalarlo como python-nmap, entonces hice:

```
pip3 uninstall nmap
pip3 install python-nmap
```

Pero ahora tengo el siguiente error:

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alejandro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 131, in __init__
    os.getenv('PATH')
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /home/alejandro/anaconda3/bin:/home/alejandro/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
>>>
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que python no encuentra nmap instalado en el sistema, la librería nmap de python depende directamente de que nmap este instalado en el sistema donde se ejecutará el script python que usa la librería.

Para ubuntu / Debian o derivados.

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Para Red Hat o derivados:

```
sudo yum install nmap
```

Para arch puedes usar

```
sudo pacman -S nmap
```

Para Suse puedes usar:

```
zypper install nmap
```

o si dispones de snap puedes usar:

```
sudo snap install nmap
```

Espero te sea útil. un saludo.